# javascript access key value pair from a string

Tags: javascript

In the following string how can i access the elements For ex:

```
var s= "{4:123,5:456}" 
for(var i=0;i<s.split(",").length;i++)
{
        console.log(s[i][0]) // should give me 4,5
        console.log(s[i][1]) // should give me 123,456

}
```

Comment: `s` looks like a JSON object to me... O__o

Comment: it is a json object in the string format

Comment: I'm probably going to be murdered for mentioning this but... ``eval``?

Comment: _s_ is not a string, rather JSON object.

Comment: @Kippie, let the murdering begin. Also, check out `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Sorry yes s = "{4:123,5:456}"

Comment: I'm also struggling to understand how splitting that string over the `,` will yield those two outputs..? Here's the [split function reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Comment: i am fine with converting string to json()

Comment: Annoyingly, I'd just written up an answer for the version without the quotes ...

Comment: Comment meltdown over a simple string-based JSON object problem! ;D

Comment: @rid It *should*, but for some reason it's throwing an error instead. Someone's already posted an answer pretty much identical now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be like:

```
   var s= {4:123,5:456} 
   for(var entry in s)
   {
        console.log(entry); // should give me 4,5
        console.log(s[entry]); // should give me 123,456
   }
```